# Set navigation bottom bar color programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Is there away i can set the colour of may navigationController bottom bar colour.  Similar to setting top bar in the app delegate with

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setBackgroundColor:color];
```

can bottomBarColor or something be used?

thanks

[image]

Comment: What do you mean navigation controller bottom bar? Toolbar? Tabbar?

Comment: It is called Bottom Bar, or at least that is what it is called in the Simulated Metrics header.  The footer bar of navigationController.

Comment: the navigation controller has no bottom or footer bar. Is a tabbar controller involved?

Comment: i've included a screen shot, the simulation metrics refers to the bar at the bottom (in orange, tool/tab bar??) as Bottom Bar. Is this the toolbar and how can i programatically set the colour?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you mistakenly believe that the bar you see at the bottom is a real bar instance/object.

It is not, it is just a simulation of a future situation. 
With **bar metrics** feature in Interface Builder, you can **simulate a situation** when you view controller will be a part of larger view hierarchy which will contain a bar at a bottom. You can simulate this in design time, and this way you can adjust your AutoLayout constraints, or frames, **as if** the bar was there so this way the constraints/ frames will behave correctly **when it really happens.**

If you want a bar with orange colour, you need to have a **real bar instance** added to some view controller, and change its appearance. But I repeat, it needs to be a real bar instance, not a bar metrics simulation.

Btw, it is AFAIK not possible to put a navigation bar to the bottom, for that you need to use `UIToolbar` class.

Comment: the bar is visible in simulator and on my device, and the colour can be set via storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the toolbar color globally do this in your AppDelegates didFinishLanchingWithOptions method:

```
[[UIToolbar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Of course your selected color doesn't have to be black.